# Can a shield that has both armor and attack enhancements exceed +10 total enhancement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

A shield can receive enhancement bonuses to both AC and Attack. Do both types of enhancements count against the maximum possible bonus (+5)?

For example, can I have a shield that has +5 to AC, the Arrow Deflection property (effective +2), +5 to Attack, and Flaming (effective +1), for a total of +13?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, shields-as-weapons are completely separate from shields-as-protection even if they are the same physical object. They each have separate +5 enhancement bonus limits and +10 total limits. And they both require separate +1 enhancement bonuses on them before you can add special magic properties.

Comment: ...What does that mean in practice, though?

Comment: @Stackstuck that means you can do what I said in the question, have a shield with +5 AC and +5 to Attack and some other magic properties, beyond the usual +10 limit. It could even have +20 total (+10 defense and +10 offense).