# How much does a shield that is also a magic weapon cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, shield, pricing

How would a shield that is both a magic armor and a magic weapon be costed?
For example, I want a shield with +5 to AC and +5 to Attack. Does it cost the same as a +10 shield? Or does it cost the same as a +5 shield plus a +5 weapon?

This is related to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80753/can-a-shield-that-has-both-armor-and-attack-enhancements-exceed-10-total-enhanc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is the same as the related question: the magic is completely separate. So the cost is just one plus the other. They do not get lumped together for pricing.

So a +5 enhancement bonus to the shield bonus is 25,000 gp and a +5 enhancement bonus to attack and damage is 50,000 gp; it costs 75,000 gp to add both a masterwork shield (which must be masterwork both as a shield/armor, for 150 gp, and as a weapon, for 300 gp, so the shield itself is worth at least 450 gp before the magic is applied).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50699/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-how-much-does-a-shield-that-is-also-a-magic-weapon).