# Do weapons that are both melee and ranged have separate enhancement bonuses?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80753/can-a-shield-that-has-both-armor-and-attack-enhancements-exceed-10-total-enhanc) seems to need a few followups.  If a shield is enchanted as a shield and as a weapon separately, are *types of weapons that can be used in different ways* e.g. stabbing vs. throwing dagger (or, for that matter, shielding vs. bashing vs. throwing *shield,* or a hypothetical projectile/melee weapon), enchanted with melee/ranged abilities separately?

Answer (score 5):

No.

Shields only operate this way because of this rule:

> An enhancement bonus on a shield does not improve the effectiveness of a shield bash made with it, but the shield can be made into a magic weapon in its own right.

<sup>([Light shield description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/shield-light-wooden-or-steel), similar statements exist for other shields capable of attacking)</sup>

I can’t prove a negative, but it is a fact that no such rule exists for other weapons in general. This rule only applies to shields. Even if a similar rule did exist for some specific weapon, it would only apply to that weapon.

One specific class of weapons that *do* have a similar rule, for instance, are double weapons:

> Creating magic double-headed weapons is treated as creating two weapons when determining cost, time, and special abilities.

<sup>([Creating Magic Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#Creating_Magic_Weapons); note that despite referring to “special abilities” specifically, [this applies to all magical benefits](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9o9e))</sup>

The two ends of a double weapon are magically enhanced separately, so each qualifies for special abilities separately, and you attack with each end separately, and so only the properties of that end are relevant.

Other weapons with separate “modes” would just apply all of their magic to all of their uses (or at least as much of the magic as could legally apply to that use; you have [asked about that separately, though](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206371/4563)).